# Do virtuals get passed when model.discriminator() is called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a schema that will have some fields and some virtuals and use it as a base to create two discriminator models. So, I was wondering if the virtuals will get passed to the discriminators or not. Thanks in advance!